# Why I cannot assign values to a variable with if and if else statements?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int leftover;
    int gold = 3900;//satisfies the if else statement

    if( gold>=4100){//successfully build item
        leftover = gold-4100;
    }
    else if(4100>gold>=3500){
        leftover = gold-3500;
    }

    cout << leftover << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

This code doesn't work, it will show that leftover is used without being initialized. But when I changed the value of gold(etc 4200) to satisfy the if statement, it will work, displaying the remainder after gold has been deducted from 4100. I am just learning c++ in school so I am not familiar with if and if else statements yet so many thanks for telling me what went wrong!

Comment: Python is the only language I know that supports such shared operands in comparison expressions. Anyway, the `void main` makes the code needlessly non-portable. Use standard `int main`. Also, you don't need the `system("pause");` at the end. E.g. in Visual Studio run the program with `Ctrl+F5`.

Comment: IMO, an even better idea would be to run the compiler from the command line to understand more about what happens behind the scenes. I think all the `system("pause")` business originates from the discontinued "DevC++" IDE which inserted this line at the end of `main` by default in all new projects :(

Answer (score 9):

`4100>gold>=3500` doesn't do what you think. It's evaluated as `(4100>gold) >= 3500`, which depending on the value of `gold` can be `0 >= 3500` or `1>3500`. Look up operator precedence.

You probably want

```
(4100>gold) && (gold>=3500)
```

Comment: I think `gold < 4100` is more readable. In fact, I think `(gold >= 3500) && (gold < 4100)` would be best, because it corresponds more closely to natural language use. Now of course, natural language use depends on what your natural language actually is, but at least in English or German or all other languages I know, you'd say something along the lines of "if gold is smaller than 4100" rather than "if 4100 is greater than gold".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize the value and the if statements fail, then you cout null  
You have two suggestions here: 
FIRST: 
    int leftover = -1; //Initialize the value

SECOND: 
    else { leftover = 0; } //Default the value if the if case fails

Answer (score 0):

Yea I made a VERY careless mistake, the only problem is 4100>gold>3500 will never get evaluated. 
Thanks to all who answered and pointed out to use AND gate instead of shared operands!